# Trigger an email when some a certain file becomes available in some location

Tags: python, email, automation

newbie here.

I have been learning Python for 3 months now because my team uses it to handle big data. I am almost done fully automating the end-to-end process of producing our monthly financials, except for one crucial step:

I need to trigger an email when the extract becomes available.

Basically, I want to do this:

if file F exists in folder Downstream:

Then send email to self.

I will then confirm running the entire process by replying some code word to this email.

TIA!

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Python's [email library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) but usually, the examples are not really straightforward and simple especially if you are new. For this reason, I actually made a package that most likely is enough for your needs regarding sending emails.

Just pip install it:

```
pip install redmail
```

Then to solve your problem:

```
from pathlib import Path
from redmail import EmailSender
email = EmailSender(
    host="<YOUR SMTP SERVER>",
    port=1,
    user_name="you@example.com", # If not needed, don't pass this
    password="<YOUR PASSWORD>" # If not needed, don't pass this
)

# Check if file exists
if Path("path/to/file.csv").is_file():
    # File does exists, send the email
    email.send(
        receivers=["you@example.com"],
        subject="File is now found",
    )
```

If you want to include a message, pass `text` and/or `html` parameters and write the email message as a string. You may also set the `receivers` as a default (attribute of the `email` instance) if repeatedly send you an email in different sections of your code.

Red Mail is well tested and well documented open-source library with features such as including attachments, embedding images, templating text or HTML and preformatted errors.

Documentation: https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Source code: https://github.com/Miksus/red-mail

Note that `pathlib` is from standard library. It is a handy library for manipulating file paths. You could also use `os.path.exists` if you prefer that.